# Trigger is Properly Working but stuck in Code Coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I am looking for help to Create a test class for my trigger.
when leads enter in database and associate with a camapign,i want to add that campaign as a campaigninfluence (opportunity related list) record in opportunity when lead is converted. Number of campaign may be more then one.
like..
A lead associate with  campaign 'A' to the time of creation and get added with one or more campaign after the creation so we have multiple campaign in "Campaign history" . when lead convert into a opportunity , i want to add  that campaigns as campaign influence in Opportunity  related list (Campaign influence).
first campaign
first campaign of lead should have 100% influence and rest of them must have 0% influence.

trigger :

```
    trigger Add_as_Campaigninfluence on Lead ( After update)  {
    map <Opportunity,Id> OppsAndContacts = new map <Opportunity,Id>(); 

    integer influence_Percentage = 100;
    Campaigninfluence[] C = new list<Campaigninfluence>();
    Integer i=0;
    string var = null;
    string var2 = null;
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        var=l.convertedcontactid;
        var2=l.convertedopportunityid;
        If(l.IsConverted){ 
            Opportunity Opp = [SELECT Id from Opportunity where Id = :l.convertedopportunityid];
            OppsAndContacts.put(Opp, l.ConvertedContactID);
        }
    }
    List <CampaignMember> cmm =[SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId = :var ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS FIRST];
    for(CampaignMember ii:cmm)
    {
        Campaigninfluence ci =new Campaigninfluence(CampaignId =ii.CampaignId,ContactId=var,OpportunityId=var2,ModelId='03V6F000000LIvWUAW',Influence= influence_Percentage);
            c.add(ci);
        influence_Percentage=0;
    }
    insert c;
}
```

test class :

```
    @isTest
public class Add_as_Campaigninfluence_test { 

    public static testmethod void unitTest(){
       Lead l = new lead(lastname ='facebook1',company='twit1');
        insert l;

        Lead leadupdate = [select id from Lead where lastname='facebook1' LIMIT 1];
        leadupdate.lastName='linkedIn1';
        update leadupdate;

        Campaigninfluence[] Camp = new list<Campaigninfluence>();
        database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadupdate.Id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        system.debug('lcr' +lcr);

        if(l.IsConverted){

            //create opportunity from lead
            Date Closedate = Date.newInstance(2017,06,03);
            opportunity opp = new opportunity();
            opp.id = l.ConvertedOpportunityId;
            system.debug('id'+ l.ConvertedOpportunityId );
            opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
            opp.CloseDate = Closedate;
            opp.Name = 'Rahul';
            update opp;

            //create account creation
            account a = new account();
            a.Name = 'company';
            a.Id = l.ConvertedAccountId;
            update a;

            //create contact record
            contact con = new contact();
            con.LastName = 'Rahul';
            con.id = l.ConvertedContactId;
            update con;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seeAllData set in test class is real bad, you should turn it off and create your own data.

Comment: Why are you inserting CampaignInfluence records in your test class. Isn't that what your trigger is supposed to do? And never hard code Ids. You need to assert values, etc. - Your trigger is not ready to be tested yet.....SOQL in loop...

Comment: Also your trigger is not bulkified, you have queries inside a for loop. Visit trailhead to learn best practices and how to write trigger and test classes properly.

Comment: i have edit and remove seeAllData Rahul i am not inserting campaign influence record any more and remove hardCode ids and SOQL is not in loop now  @Eric  please have a look /Updated/ let me know for any issue                                 thank you Eric &  Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Good work on taking the comments and making changes..

You trigger works on *Update* and if the lead is converted it gets the related contacts.

- If the lead is updated after conversion it will run again so you need to account for that

**Test**

Write a test method that

- simply creates a lead then updates it
- Assert
  that no campaign influence records were created. May seem silly but
  if the trigger changes later it may do this when you do not want it
  to

Next, your trigger takes those contacts and queries the CampaignMember records

- How do your CampaignMember records get completed?
- You will need to know this in order to complete the tests, for now I am going to assume you need to create them. but if they are automatic you will need to address that in the code

**Test**

Write a test method that

- creates a lead
- Create the campaign member records
- Convert the lead
  -**Assert** that the appropriate Campaign Influence records are created

When writing a test look at what the trigger is doing. Determine the different positive and negative branches it takes, and what data it needs to run. Then write your tests for each of those cases, providing the data the trigger needs and then asserting the results. You do not create records that the trigger itself creates. (i.e. when lead is converted it creates an opp so you do not need to create the opp in your test)